# Save canvas and use it as background img

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, storage

Any-Kind-Soul-Out-there,

I spending hours figuring out how could i done the coding in such a way that when after user drawn on the canvas, they can click a btn called "save". After which the canvas's image will appear as a BG img of the webpage.

Even after user close the web browser, the bg img is still there when user open it again. I'm not sure is it possible to do it or not.
Need some help here, if need my full coding i can provide.

Below is my current coding when user clicked "save" btn. (Open new window as an image.)

```
// Save image
var saveImage = document.createElement("button");
saveImage.innerHTML = "Save canvas";
saveImage.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    evt.preventDefault();
}, false);
document.getElementById("main-content").appendChild(saveImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use toDataURL to set the background, and localStorage to store 'permanently' the image :

http://jsbin.com/japekuzi/1/

use draw to fill the canvas with random rects, and set button to set and store current canvas as background.

Notice that when you (re)run the jsbin, it stills keeps its latest background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id='cv'></canvas>
  <button id='dr'>draw</button>
  <button id='st'>set</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS :

```
var $=document.getElementById.bind(document);
var cv  = $('cv');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');

function randFill() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cv.width, cv.height);
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var c= 0 | ( Math.random()* 360);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl('+c+',75%,75%)';
    ctx.fillRect(Math.random()*cv.width*0.8, 
                 Math.random()*cv.height*0.8, 20, 20);
  }
}

function set() {
  localStorage.setItem("bg", cv.toDataURL());
  retrieve();
}

function retrieve() {
  var cvURL =   localStorage.getItem("bg", cv.toDataURL());
  if (!cvURL) return;
  document.body.style. backgroundImage ='url('+ cvURL+')';  
}

randFill();
retrieve();

$('dr').onclick=randFill;
$('st').onclick=set;
```